# Getting a range of table cells with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to write a jQuery selector to select a range of table cells (minRow, minCol) to (maxRow, maxCol).

I have a selector that works for a horizontal range (col 1, row 2) to (col 3, row 2)
`$('tr:lt(3):gt(1) td:lt(4):gt(0))')`

But this fails for the corresponding vertical range (col 2, row 1) to (col 2, row 3)
`$('tr:lt(4):gt(0) td:lt(3):gt(1)')`
because the td selector won't loop over the row, it will just take the first one

This version using map and each works
`$('tr:lt(4):gt(0)').map( function() { return $(this).find('td:lt(3):gt(1)') } ).each( function() { /* this.do_something */ } );`
but is even uglier

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Bonus points for finding a more elegant range selector than `:lt():gt()`

Examples of the above horizontal and vertical ranges and a block range are at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jghaines/qeLhgw4f/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `tr:lt(3):gt(1) td:lt(4):gt(0)` only works because a single row is being selected. What's happening is `tr:lt(3):gt(1)` will return a set of `td` elements in row 3, and `td:lt(4):gt(0)` will select the second, third, and fourth `td` elements by their index in **that specific set**.

When you use a selector like `tr:lt(4):gt(0) td:lt(3):gt(1)`, multiple rows are selected and the selectors are compounded relative to the set that is returned (rather than each individual `td` element). The selector `tr:lt(4):gt(0)` returns a set consisting of the second, third, and fourth rows. Based on this returned set, the selector `td:lt(3):gt(1)` will select the third `td` element by its index in **that specific set**.

In other words, the `:gt()`/`:lt()` selectors will select all elements at an index greater than or less than an index **within the matched set**. Your selectors weren't working as expected because the elements were being selected based on the matched set (rather than each individual `td` element).

The solution would be to chain a `.find()` method between `tr:lt(4):gt(0)`/`td:lt(3):gt(1)`.

In other words, replace:

```
$('table#2 tr:lt(4):gt(0) td:lt(3):gt(1)').addClass('red');
```

With:

```
$('table#2 tr:lt(4):gt(0)').find('td:lt(3):gt(1)').addClass('red');
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmeoLvn5/)

---

Since you wanted an alternative to combining `:lt():gt()`, it's worth pointing out that you can use the `.slice()` method:

For instance, you could replace:

```
$('table#2 tr:lt(4):gt(0) td:lt(3):gt(1)').addClass('red');
```

With:

```
$('table#2 tr').slice(1, 4).find('td:lt(3):gt(1)').addClass('red');
```

Comment: Terrific, thanks. I note that the slice will only work on the first tr selector. This does not work: `$('table#4 tr').slice(1,4).find('td').slice(1,4).addClass('yellow'); `